# Audio Kit UI NodeRollingView, ways to adjust it?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, viewcontroller, audiokit

I am pretty new to AudioKit, and I was wondering is there a way to adjust sample rate, color and margins for the NodeRollingView?
I am creating the view similarly to the CookBook sample project:

```
struct LevelView: View {
    @StateObject var conductor = TunerConductor()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           
            NodeRollingView(conductor.tappableNodeA).clipped()

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Level One")
        .onAppear {
            conductor.start()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            conductor.stop()
        }
   
        
    }
}
```

To be more specific:
I am trying to use NRV to draw which note a person in singing into the microphone.
Something like [this](https://audiokitpro.com/build-a-singing-tutor-app-with-audiokit/) tutorial.
Since AKFrequencyTracker no longer exist.

EDIT:
So basically the output looks like this, but I want to make it much smoother with reduced noise, so that you can actually understand what frequency is being played:
[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2MS.png)
And this what I want it to look as(see the red line)
With the large empty area on the top being filled as well:
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwrYQ.jpg)

Looking at the code of the NRV, it has a public init, but I am not sure how to use it:

```
 public init(_ node: Node, color: Color = .gray, bufferSize: Int = 1024) {
metalFragment = FragmentBuilder(foregroundColor: color.cg, isCentered: false, isFilled: false)     nodeTap = RawDataTap(node, bufferSize: UInt32(bufferSize)) }
```

`

Comment: In terms of color, you can just add `color: .green` to your current call site (`NodeRollingView(conductor.tappableNodeA, color: .green)`). As you see in the `init`, it has a default value, so it is optional to include it. Same with the buffer size. I'm not sure what you mean by changing the sample rate -- having the view use a different sample rate than the node would lead to pretty strange results. Lastly, with margins, perhaps you're just looking for `padding()` in SwiftUI?

Comment: So if you actually look at the output its very jittery - not smooth. I want to reduce the amount of sample that are done each second, but increase the size of each point, which will result in a much smoother line. And it terms of margins, I want to set both the lowest frequency and the highest frequency think C1 and C6 as example, so that the graph bounces between the two values representitive of the note recieved as input

Comment: Please look at the edit for more clarity